# SSRS-Repeat Tablix group

Tags: reporting-services

I have a tablix that has the following groups:
Location, Customer, Contract Number, Serial Number
The details of my report consist of various invoice amounts (i.e. cost & price) and are totaled for each group.  The groups are always displayed regardless if there are any invoices. So if there were no invoices for the serial number, $0.00 is displayed. 
Here's the question...
There are 2 types of invoice amounts - we will call them "contract transcations" and "non-contract transactions".  My end users want to see the contract transcations separated out from the non-contract transactions on a separate section.  So basically all of the same group information repeats on the next page, but I will add a filter (either in the group or in the fields themselves to determine the amount to display based on the type of transaction).  I'm thinking I just need to insert a new group, but I can't figure out what to group it by or how to get everything to repeat.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to approach this.

**Add a Parent Group**

Add a new group that is a parent (higher in the hierarchy) than all other groups. Group on the field that separates contract versus non-contract transactions.

**Add a second tablix**

Depending on how you want the report to flow, it may be easier to copy your existing tablix (or otherwise duplicate it) to another spot on the page, at which point you can set a filter on each tablix to display only one type of transaction. Note, this method requires more maintenance but also more customization. If you need to change a font or a color or expression, then you need to change it in both places. This can become tedious depending on the amount of tweaks, but it also allows for a lot of customization that might be difficult to do with IIF expressions in just one tablix.

**What to do if you don't have a field to indicate Contract versus Non-Contract Transactions**

In your question, you said you were sure what to group on, making me think you may not have one field that indicates whether something is or is not a contract transaction. If that is the case, then you need to do one of two things:

*1. Create a field in your dataset which specifies transaction type*

In this scenario, you need to either find a field somewhere in your database(s) that tells you whether a transaction is or is not a contract transaction, or you need to add logic (presumably a case statement) in your select statement which will allow you to differentiate between the two types.

*2. Create an expression in SSRS that differentiates between the two transaction types*

In this scenario, you are more comfortable with using the VB.NET function set in SSRS to delineate between the transaction types. Whatever you do, make sure the expression returns a value that makes apparent sense. You wouldn't, for example, want to return a 0 for contract transactions and a 1 for non-contract transactions, because then you'd have to amend that function in certain instances to subsequently change a 0 to "Contract Transactions" and 1 to "Non-Contract Transactions".